# Add description to code tag

Tags: listings, code

I didn't find answer how to add description to my simple code listing. It looks like that:

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
{
    \noindent
    \minipage{\linewidth} 
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,frame=single,#1}}
{\endminipage}


\begin{code}[frame=tb]
    ...
    <users>
        <user resources="*" password="password" name="userName"/>
    </users>
    ...
\end{code}
```

I would like to enumerate this code tag with its description in the same way as my graphics and tables are.
Do anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Which package do you use for the `code` environment? Please complete your snippet to a little, *complete* document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `caption` or the `title` keys. The former will give you automatic numbering, a heading (of the form Listing #) and the possibility to include the caption text in an eventual list of listings (produced through `\lstlistoflistings`); the latter will typeset the text as a title.

A complete example showing both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
{
    \noindent
    \minipage{\linewidth} 
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,frame=single,#1}}
  {\endminipage}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}[frame=tb,caption={a description of the code goes here}]
    ...
    <users>
        <user resources="*" password="password" name="userName"/>
    </users>
    ...
\end{code}

\begin{code}[frame=tb,title={A title for the code goes here}]
    ...
    <users>
        <user resources="*" password="password" name="userName"/>
    </users>
    ...
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]